# How to extract .gz file with .txt extension folder?

Tags: perl, gzip, unzip

I'm currently stuck with this problem where my .gz file is "some_name.txt.gz" (the .gz is not visible, but can be recognized with `File::Type` functions),
and inside the .gz file, there is a FOLDER with the name "some_name.txt", which contains other files and folders.

However, I am not able to extract the archive as you would manually (the folder with the name "some_name.txt" is extracted along with its contents) when calling the extract function from the `Archive::Extract` because it will just extract the "some_name.txt" folder as a .txt file.

I've been searching the web for answers, but none are correct solutions. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the .gz is not visible?"

Comment: oh just means it's missing the extensions when you view it on the computer, but it's recognized as a .gz file no problem

Comment: I'm a bit confused, my impression of the .gz format is that is a single-file compression routine, good for compressing simple files or larger archive files like those in .tar format.  If you explain what "manual" command you'd use to open up this .gz file, we may be able to guide you in opening up the archive compressed within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Archive::Extract](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Extract.html) official doc

"Since .gz files never hold a directory, but only a single file;"

I would recommend using tar on the folder and then gz it.
That way you can use [Archive::Tar](http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html) to easily extract specific file:

Example from official docs:

> $tar->extract_file( $file, [$extract_path] )
>   Write an entry, whose name is equivalent to the file name provided to disk. Optionally takes a second parameter, which is the full native path (including filename) the entry will be written to.
>   For example:

```
$tar->extract_file( 'name/in/archive', 'name/i/want/to/give/it' );
$tar->extract_file( $at_file_object,   'name/i/want/to/give/it' );
```

> Returns true on success, false on failure.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can identify these files with File::Type, rename them with .gz extension instead of .txt, then try Archive::Extract on it?

Comment: the name.txt FOLDER is in the .gz archive, so I can't modify it unless I extract it, but if I do, it would come out as an unreadable .txt file. this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Does Archive::Extract think it's a gz file?  (Using the [quick check methods](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Archive-Extract-0.68/lib/Archive/Extract.pm)).

Comment: yes, it has no problem recognizing the .gz archive itself. the problem is in the extracting. it gets confused when extracting a folder with name.txt, so it recognizes the folder as a .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

A gzip file can only contain a single file. If you have an archive file that contains a folder plus multiple other files and folders, then you may have a gzip file that contains a tar file. Alternatively you may have a zip file.

Can you give more details on how the archive file was created and a listing of it contents?